# How to run a function once inside the animation loop in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to run a function once when a condition is true in Three.js.

I am sampling the FPS to send to a external service. The FPS is sampled and averaged. When I have 10 samples, the average is calculated and sent.

The FPS calculation is inspired from the Stats plugin to Three.js.

The problem is that this gets run multiple times(`sendInfo()`), it seems like it gets run the same amount of times as the FPS. (When FPS = 55, it gets run 55 times)

How can I avoid this? I only want it to call `sendInfo()` once.

Here is a sample of my animate() loop: (some vars are declared outside)

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate, renderer.domElement);

    var beginTime = performance.now();

    // Plus some computations, raycasting etc here

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    var endTime = performance.now();

    frames ++;

    if (endTime > prevTime + 1000) {

        var fps = Math.round(frames * 1000 / (endTime - prevTime));

        fpsLog.push(fps);

        prevTime = endTime;
        frames = 0;
    }

    // When fpsLog has enough values to calculate a average from, we run function
    if (fpsLog.length === 10) {

        var totalFps = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < fpsLog.length; i++) {
            totalFps += fpsLog[i];
        }

        var averageFps = Math.ceil(totalFps / fpsLog.length); //round up to nearest integer

        sendInfo(averageFps); // send fps info to external service <--- THIS ONE GETS RUN MULTIPLE TIMES (it seems like its equal to the FPS, around 56-59 times on my computer)
    }
}
```

I have tried to set a boolean after the `sendInfo()` is called, and checking this in the `if (fpsLog.lenght === 10)`, but same result.

```
    if (fpsLog.length === 10 && isExecuted === false) {

        var totalFps = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < fpsLog.length; i++) {
            totalFps += fpsLog[i];
        }

        var averageFps = Math.ceil(totalFps / fpsLog.length); //round up to nearest integer

        sendInfo(averageFps); // send fps info to external service <--- THIS ONE GETS RUN MULTIPLE TIMES (it seems like its equal to the FPS, around 56-59 times on my computer)
        isExecuted = true;
    }
```

Comment: where did you "set the boolean"? Show the code declaring `isExecuted`

Comment: Tried to add it now outside the animate() loop, and it worked! Thank you. I think I declared it inside the animate() loop earlier..

Comment: yea that's why I asked - if you declare it inside `animate` it will be `false` every time it hits the `if`. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the isExecuted variable outside the animate() loop solved this.

Answer (score 0):

dunno if it helps, BUT:

I used to have:  onTransitionEnd: run a function = bad, runs everytime animation or transition happens

I swapped it to: onAnimationEnd: run a function = fixed, runs 1 time

after onAnimationEnd, my Div Transitions and changes size, BUT the function is NOT triggered.